# Why didn't Hagoromo reincarnate dead shinobis after the Fourth Great Ninja War?

Tags: naruto

If Pain was able to resurrect Kakashi along with the other dead Konohagakure villagers, why did Hagoromo not reincarnate dead shinobis after the Fourth Great Ninja War?

Comment: Because he's already dead. The jutsu - Gedo Art of Rinne Rebirth - can infuse new life into the bodies of those who have died in exchange for the user's own life. Hagoromo couldn't use it in the "form" he was even if he wanted to.

Comment: @ Ōtsutsuki  it's not exchange of user life,bcoz when pain uses Gedo Art of Rinne Rebirth jutsu ,Rinnegan consumes a lot of chakra. As Nagato already had nearly exhausted his chakra reserves, he died due to all his chakra being depleted.

Comment: @Lavakusa This was stated in the wiki: 'Ultimately, once the technique is finished, the user invariably dies.' This means that the user will always die regardless if he exhausted his/her chakra reserves or not. I verified the chapter source and it is legit. Source: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Outer_Path_—_Samsara_of_Heavenly_Life_Technique

Comment: Actually @W.Are Nagato had previously used the samsara of heavenly life technique to revive the pains that were killed by both Jiraiya and Naruto but he didn't die until he tried a large scale version of the jutsu, so i do believe chakra reserves are a big factor in the Jutsu. If that weren't the case then he should have died after he revived the pains that Jiraiya killed.

Comment: However maybe the fact that he was doing it through one of the pains affected its effects.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin Really? I might be wrong but I thought that it was a different technique and it was one of the Pains who revived the Pains that were killed: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naraka_Path

Comment: @Lavakusa The fourth databook clarified that usage of this technique comes at the cost of the user's life.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin The Six Paths of Pain are corpses they're not alive. They were never revived through the technqiue. And if they were "destroyed", the Naraka Path repairs them as was seen with the Asura Path. He is controlling them solely with his chakra hence the black receivers in the bodies of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @Ōtsutsuki's comment, Hagoromo Ōtsutsuki *did not manifest himself physically to Naruto since he is alread dead*. The scene where they were talking *happened in Naruto's mind* (**Chapter 670**). How he was able to share his powers with Naruto and Sasuke if he's already dead was never elaborated on in the manga, as far as I know. [image]

The [Gedo Art of Rinne Rebirth](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Outer_Path_%E2%80%94_Samsara_of_Heavenly_Life_Technique) *requires the user's life in exchange for another's*. Hagoromo is already dead, and he only manifested himself in Naruto's mind. It's quite hard to classify someone in this state as 'alive'. With this, we can say that *you cannot offer your life for someone else's if you have already lost it in the first place*.

Comment: it's not exchange of life,  I read above mentioned  Narutopedia article in this            
"While using this technique, the user is severely weakened as a result of overexerting their power." But Hagoromo  has lot of chakra even though he is dead and he able to summon all hokages , means he has lot chakra.

Comment: @Lavakusa It is an exchange of life. If you can cite a chapter that says that someone cannot die after using Rinne Rebirth, then please do so. I'm finding it hard to believe this. And how was he able to summon those hokage? As far as I know it was Orochimaru who used Edo Tensei to bring back the 4 previous Hokage.

Comment: but Hagoromo used Edo Tensei to bring back the hokages sealed by allied shinobi's , proof :- Second Tsuchikage

Comment: @Lavakusa Edo Tensei is different from Rinne Rebirth. Edo Tensei does not truly bring back a person to life, unlike Rinne Rebirth since 'their body will never again be theirs', as stated here: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation Also, it was Kabuto who summoned the second tsuchikage, not Hagoromo. Hagoromo cannot perform jutsu because again, he only manifested in the inner thoughts of Sasuke and Naruto, and he was not truly alive with a physical form and all.

Comment: @Lavakusa If you are referring to this: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kaguya_%C5%8Ctsutsuki_Strikes Then he only summoned them. It was not stated that he performed Rinne Rebirth or Edo Tensei to do so.

Comment: Adding to what @W.Are said, Edo tensei required literally no chakra from its user, thats why it is the MOST OVERPOWERED JUTSU EVER! Also, Hagoromo never used Edo tensei, the only people who used it in the war were Kabuto, Obito, Madara, and Orochimaru. Edo tensei requires a human sacrifice to be used, Hagoromo was not the type of person to use such means so i'm guessing we can rule out Edo Tensei